# Retrive value from payload and convert to CSV with Dataweave

Tags: csv, transform, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, payload

Hi I have this example payload. And I would save it to CSV but I don't need all value only a few.

```
{
    "ex": "names",
    "At": 0,
    "start": 50,
    "total": 506,
    "TypeI": [
        {
            "firstOne": "operations",
            "id": "28",
            "key": "192",
                "timespent": null,
                "project": {
                    "id": "10",
                    "key": "2",
                    "name": "PSM2",
                    "projectTypeKey": "software"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "firstOne": "opera",
            "id": "27778",
            "key": null,
                "timespent": null,
                "project": {
                    "id": "10",
                    "key": "2",
                    "name": "PSM2",
                    "projectTypeKey": "software"
                }
        
            }
         }   
    ]
}
```

I don't want change the structure of this payload. I need only a few value from this and then I would like write it to CSV.

I got this payload with the same key and now I would like to save it to CSV. I have problem with the type. Now I got the string. But I need the array of object to save it in CSV.

```
{
  "TypeI": [
    {
      "firstOne": "operations",
       "date": "2022-03-25T14:12:25.702+0100",
      "id": "28",
      "key": "192"
    },
    {
      "firstOne": "opera",
      "date": null default " ", 
      "id": "27778",
      "key": null default " "
    }
  ]
}
```

This is example how it would like the CSV

```
firstOne;date;id;key
operations;2022-03-25T14:12:25.702+0100;28;192
opera;  ;27778;
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: @Anonim Please explain the question properly to able to help you. how do you want the data in CSV, please give an example for that too?

Comment: And what is exactly the data that you want? Just saying a few values is totally ambiguous. Be as specific as possible.

Comment: So first I would like retrieve only same value but I don't want change the structure. I know that I can do that example {firstOne:  payload.TypeI.firstOne}. But if the key are the same it would be like this firstOne: [ "operations", "opera'] etc. And this way change the structure of payload. And it's possible retrieve the value but the structure of payload stay? And then I would like save it to CSV. I hope it will be more clearly.

Comment: Also I know that there are same null and I think to use default " ".(empty string) Because I think null value it would be the problem for CSV. I'm not sure if it's good practice for this.

Comment: @AnuragSharma Hi I solve one problem form my post and add the solution. Now I need save this structure to CSV. I explain again and I hope it's more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solve one problem.

```
    %dw 2.0
    import update from dw::util::Values
    output application/json
    ---
     TypeI : (payload.TypeI map ((item, index) -> {
        "firstOne": item.firstOne,
        "date": item.court.date,
        "id": item.id,
        "key": item.key
    } ))
```

And I got the json without change the structure of my json.
Now the second part my question to save this to CSV.